# Nohup: can't detach from console

Tags: linux, macos, bash, nohup

I have a bash script that will run in both Linux and Mac OS X. One particular line of the script works as is in Linux, but not in OS X.

```
nohup <utility> <arg> > output.txt 2> error.txt </dev/null &
```

When the bash script runs in Linux, it works like a charm. However, running the bash script in OS X, I get the error

```
nohup: can't detach from console: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I've done a lot of searching and haven't found a suitable answer as to why this is behaving as such.

The executing script exits long before the `<utility>`, which is why (as far as my knowledge goes) I need to use `nohup`. However, I've done some testing, and removing `nohup` from the line in the bash script seems do the trick in that the utility on both systems will launch, and continue to run even after the script exits.

Comment: Are you running the script from the ordinary terminal?

Comment: Are you running this inside a `tmux` or `screen` session? There is a known bug when these interact with `nohup`. Patches are available to fix the bug.

Comment: @KristerAndersson The script is executed by STAF automation.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick No tmux or screen sessions

Comment: If `STAF automation`, like `tmux` and `screen`, calls `daemon()` to detach from a terminal, it may run into the same problem when running `nohup`. A workaround is described in https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard ; compile the `reattach-to-user-namespace` program and then run `reattach-to-user-namespace nohup ...`

Comment: `nohup` is a useless, pointless utility. `utility arg >output.txt 2>error.txt </dev/null & disown -h "$!"` does literally everything nohup does _built into the shell itself_. (That's in large part because most of what nohup does is _also_ done by `>output.txt 2>error.txt </dev/null`; with those three redirections, you made nohup almost irrelevant in the first place!)

Comment: (and the `disown` is only necessary in an interactive shell; a noninteractive shell doesn't forward HUP signals in the first place, making `nohup` _doubly_ useless)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
nohup <utility> <arg> > output.txt 2> error.txt >/dev/null &
```

Comment: Tested. No go. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
nohup <utility> <arg> > output.txt 2> error.txt >/dev/null & disown
```

Comment: You probably want the `-h` argument to `disown` here. And leave out the actual `nohup`; between the redirections and the `disown`, you're doing everything `nohup` does already.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need `nohup` at all**.

`nohup` has only the following features:

- It declines to forward `HUP` signals to its children (which you can also do in bash with `disown -h`).
- It redirects stdin from `/dev/null` *if it was previously pointing to a terminal* (which it isn't because you're running `</dev/null`).
- It redirects stdout to `nohup.out` *if it was previously pointing to a terminal* (which it isn't because you're running `>output.txt`).
- It redirects stderr to `nohup.out` *if it was previously pointing to a terminal* (which it isn't because you're running `2>error.txt`).

That's it. That's all it does. And you don't *need* something that'll decline to forward HUP signals unless you're in an interactive shell (because noninteractive shells with default settings don't forward HUP signals at all in the first place).