# nohup: can't detach from console: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: macos, hadoop

While starting hadoop resource manager on OSX , i am getting below error :

```
bash-3.2$ start-yarn.sh

starting yarn daemons

starting resourcemanager, logging to /Users/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/yarn-hadoop-resourcemanager-MacBook-Pro-2.local.out

nohup: can't detach from console: Inappropriate ioctl for device

localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /Users/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-MacBook-Pro-2.local.out

bash-3.2$ cat /Users/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/yarn-hadoop-resourcemanager-MacBook-Pro-2.local.out

nohup: can't detach from console: Inappropriate ioctl for device

ulimit -a

core file size (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files (-n) 256
pipe size (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes (-u) 709
virtual memory (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Comment: Likely duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898623/nohup-cant-detach-from-console

Comment: hi patrungel , this is a different issue , but i found a workaround , posting below

Answer (score 1):

I modified the script $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh , ie: removed nohup

from :

nohup nice -n $YARN_NICENESS "$HADOOP_YARN_HOME"/bin/yarn --config $YARN_CONF_DIR $command "$@" > "$log" 2>&1 < /dev/null &

to

nice -n $YARN_NICENESS "$HADOOP_YARN_HOME"/bin/yarn --config $YARN_CONF_DIR $command "$@" > "$log" 2>&1 < /dev/null &

and now i am able to start resourcemanager

Answer (score 0):

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

make

UsePAM **no**

to

UsePAM **yes**